# How to avoid "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery" error

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am running this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.CODNAT IN (SELECT item 
                               FROM fnMAS_Parametro_para_Lista('CON_SPED_FISCAL_CFOPS_BLOCO_C_FORA')) 
                THEN 0 EKSE ROUND(ISNULL(10, 0), 2) 
        END)
FROM
    ##tmpARPCO a
INNER JOIN
    ARPCO_ITENS_TOTALIZADORES b ON (b.numped = a.numped 
                                    AND b.seqped = a.seqped 
                                    AND b.tipo = 'P')
INNER JOIN
    ArEmpresa c ON (c.codempresa = a.codempresa)
INNER JOIN 
    ArNat d ON (d.codnat = b.codnat)
WHERE 
    1=1                       
    AND a.ESPEC IN ('NFE', 'NF', 'NFCE', 'NFA', 'NFFA', 'NFSE')  
    AND a.MODNF IN ('01', '1B', '04', '55', '65')                     
    AND a.datentr BETWEEN '20180401' AND '20180430' 
GROUP BY
    a.codcad, a.numnf, a.datentr, b.sittrib
```

but I get the following message:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

The function that you can see, only returns me a list of code string from a table. How to solve that problem?

Thanks a lot for your help and time

Alexandre

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)+

Comment: Why you are selecting `distinct` **and** having a `group by`?